# Immutability Issue: Warning: A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. (Opposite of

Tags: reactjs

Code:

```
   class Table extends Component {

    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            body: Body
        }
    }

    

    onChangeHandler = (event, index) => {

        const value = event.target.value;
        const body = this.state.body;
        body[index] = value;
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            body: body
        }))

    }

    render() {

        const heads = Headers.map((element, index) => <th key = {"__trow__" + index}>{element}</th>);
        const body = this.state.body.map((element, index) => <td key = {"__trow_body__" + index}>

            <div className = {classes.EditFieldCell}>
            <input type = {element.inputType} 
                   className = {classes.EditFieldCellInput}
                   value = {element.title}
                   onChange = {(event) => this.onChangeHandler(event, index)}
            >
            </input>
            </div>
            

        </td>
        );


        return <table className = {classes.prettyTable}>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            {
                heads
            }
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            {
                body
            }
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>

    }

}


export default Table;
```

I tried to update state via spread operator, this.setState, Object.assign, but none of them seem to work. I am unable to understand at which point exactly is my state getting uncontrolled.

Where `Headers = ["A","B","C"]`

and

Body = `[ {title: "Check 1",inputType: "text"}, {title: "Check 2 B",inputType: "text"},{title: "Check 1",inputType: "text"}]`

Comment: You are mutating your state here: `body[index] = value;`. [Never mutate state](https://medium.com/@kkranthi438/dont-mutate-state-in-react-6b25d5e06f42).

Comment: Oh, I see... so what is the better option here? Tried: `const body = [...this.state.body]; ` which gives me the same warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @riven and @Ravi for the assist. I realized that I was trying to update an array of objects which had two properties:

```
                   className = {classes.EditFieldCellInput}
                   value = {element.title}
```

and so I changed:
`body[index].title = value;`
to fix it.

Additionally a more sophisticated solution would be:

```
onChangeHandler = (event, index) => {

        const value = event.target.value;
        const body = [...this.state.body];
        const bodyElement = {...body[index]};

        bodyElement.title = value;
        body[index] = bodyElement;
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            body: body
        }))

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Some event is changing the value of the `input` to `undefined`.

`input` values should be set to empty values`('')` rather than `undefined`

Comment: I didn't get you... I don't think it has to do with input value to be undefined. It's more with some kind of immutability. Additionally what you suggested, I did try that as well, but it didn't work as input field then becomes constant.